# Syntax for integer variable in play framework scala

Tags: scala

I have this code where i want to initialize a variable called "qty"  for calculating the total quantity. So can you please help me with the syntax.

```
@for(itemMenu <- itemsMenu) {
            <tr>
val qty=0 //i want to initialize qty variable

            @for(itemOrders<-itemsOrders) {
                    @if(itemMenu.m_id == itemOrders.m_id) {
                         qty+=item.quantity//calculate qty value
                    }
                }
            <td>@itemMenu.item</td>
            <td>@qty</td> //print qty
            <td>@itemMenu.offer</td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: `@itemOrders.filter(_.m_id == itemMenu.m_id).sum`

Comment: it shows error at ".filter"

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function for this, which you can declare after the import section of your template:

```
@qty(itemOrders: YourType, itemMenu: YourType) = @{itemOrders.filter(_._m_id == itemMenu.m_id).map{ itemOrder =>
    itemOrder.quantity}.sum}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
@qty(itemOrders, itemMenu)
```

However, to keep your view readable, and to make your code easier to test you might want to put such logic somewhere else.